# How to improve performance of csv to parquet file format using pyspark?

Tags: performance, csv, pyspark, parquet

I have a large dataset I need to convert from csv to parquet format using pyspark. There is approximately 500GB of data scattered across thousands of csv files. My initial implementation is simplistic ...

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("test") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv(input_files, header=True, inferSchema=True)

df.repartition(1).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(output_dir)
```

The performance is abysmal, I have let it run for 2+ hours before giving up. From logging output I infer it does not even complete reading the csv files into the dataframe.

I am running spark locally on a server with 128 high performance CPU cores and 1TB of memory. Disk storage is SSD based with confirmed read speeds of 650 MB/s. My intuition is that I should be able to significantly improve performance given the computing resources available. I'm looking for tips on how to do this.

I have tried...

- not inferring schema, this did not produce a noticeable difference in performance (The schema is four columns of text)
- using the configuration setting `spark.executor.cores` to match the number of physical cores on my server. The setting did not seem to have any effect, I did not observe the system using more cores.

I'm stuck using pyspark for now per management direction, but if necessary I can convince them to use a different tool.

Comment: Are you sure you want a Parquet file without any partitioning? Having partitioned columns should give some speedup, not only in writing but also in reading and doing computations in the future.

Comment: @mck I had given that some thought, what is the best way to decide the optimal number of partitions?

Comment: It's a very broad question - Google will give you lots of answers. It really depends on your data structure.

Comment: also provide the schema - either manually, or read one CSV file by name, and read it with `inferSchema`, and then use schema from that file for reading all files

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions based on my experience working with spark :

- You should not infer the schema if you are dealing with huge data. It might not show significant improvement in the performance but definitely it would still save you some time.
- Don't use repartition(1) as it would shuffle the data and create a single partition with data and that is what you don't want with huge volume of data that you have. I would suggest you to increase the number of partitions if possible based on the cluster configuration you have in order to get the parquet files saved faster.
- Don't Cache/persist your data frame if you are just reading the csv files and then in the next step saving it as parquet files. It can increase your saving time as caching itself takes some time. Caching the data frame would have helped if you were performing multiple transformations on the data frame and then performing multiple actions on it. your are performing only one action of writing the data frame as parquet file, so according to me you should not cache the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible improvments :

- Don't use `.repartition(1)` as you lose parallelism for writing operation
- Persisit/cache the dataframe before writing : `df.persist()`

If you **really need** to save it as 1 parquet file, you can first write into temp folder without reducing partitions then use `coalesce` in a second write operation :

```
df = spark.read.csv(input_files, header=True, inferSchema=True).persist()
# ....

df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("/temp/folder")
df.unpersist()

df1 = spark.read.parquet("/temp/folder")
df1.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(output_dir)
```

Comment: Good advice on repartitioning, it's not necessary for my use case. I saw it in an example and assumed it was mandatory.